# How set wallpaper choosing position

Tags: java, android, crop, android-wallpaper

I can show in an imageview an image from url and i can set it as wallpaper as well.. But i would create something like nova launcher or google launcher method to set the wallpaper. I mean show the image in fullscreen and you can choose the position you want. What i mean is in the screen below:
[image]

This is the code i use to set the wallpaper right now:

```
Button buttonSetWallpaper = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set);
            ImageView imagePreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
            imagePreview.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);

            buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }});
```

Comment: did you get permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>?

Comment: Sure, but is not my problem.. I can set the wallpaper but i would create a view like you see in the screen i posted..

Comment: @End.Game Did you ever find a solution to this?